# Unable to initialize Loader in latest android studio. java.lang.ClassCastException:

Tags: android

I am trying to use loaders on latest android studio but its showing this error when I initialize the loader using initLoader() method. I am unable to find the solution on how to use loaders in latest android studio after its been deprecated in API 28

```
2020-12-29 18:42:02.229 29311-29311/com.example.quakereportwithloader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.quakereportwithloader, PID: 29311
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.quakereportwithloader/com.example.quakereportwithloader.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.quakereportwithloader.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.quakereportwithloader.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks
        at com.example.quakereportwithloader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:95)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
```

THIS IS HOW I INITIALIZED THE LOADER

```
android.app.LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
loaderManager.initLoader(EARTHQUAKE_LOADER_ID, null, (android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Object>) this);
```

THESE ARE MY IMPORTS

```
import androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager;
import androidx.loader.content.Loader;
```

Comment: Your activity isn't a LoaderManager

Comment: Implement 'LoaderCallbacks' in 'MainActivity".